# MySQL Insert To Account For Random CSV Rows Rolling Over PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

I am inserting a csv into a MySQL database. The problem is every so often in my csv file there is one column called `Alternates` and for some reason if its data is to long it rolls to the next row making one for row dedicated to the excess data for that column.

So if the column is named Alternates and the data is `DFE121-343431 38747`
Then 
`38747` will be rolled to the next row.

I need to find a way to account for this and make sure that that data that is being rolled will also be entered into the same row as the rest of the data that's associated with it.

I will provide some images of

The Excel File

[image]

The CSV data

[image]

The MySQL database

[image]

Please see my code that creates the table 
Opens the csv file 
converts the data and adds it to the table

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $table_name . " (
      id int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      wuno_product varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      wuno_description varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      wuno_alternates varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      wuno_onhand varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      wuno_condition varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;"; 
          $dbh->query($sql);

    if (($handle = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
           fgetcsv($handle);   
           while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $num = count($data);
                for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                  $col[$c] = $data[$c];
                }

         $col1 = $col[0];
         $col2 = $col[1];
         $col3 = $col[2];
         $col4 = $col[3];
         $col5 = $col[4];

        // SQL Query to insert data into DataBase
        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table_name . "(wuno_product, wuno_description, wuno_alternates, wuno_onhand, wuno_condition) 
        VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."','".$col4."','".$col5."')";
        $dbh->query( $sql );
        }
        fclose($handle);
```

This is an example of what the actual CSV looks like when an extra row appears

```
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58
,,5930-01-109-7580,,
```

In that case the

```
,,5930-01-109-7580,,
```

Shows up on a row after the row it goes with.

Comment: Can you clean up your excel file ?

Comment: the problem is the one i'm working with is 5k rows. when this goes into production it will be 88k long. so no way we can spend the man hours cleaning it up.

Comment: if the sample excel table above was well-formatted, how would it look?

Comment: line 5 alternates would be part of line 4 alternates. These occurrences recur throughout the file.

Comment: And that's the only difference?

Comment: There is not always data for each column but the only situation that carries to the next row is the one I have mentioned, yes.

Comment: increase the length parameter in `fgetcsv`

Comment: I changed it to no limit and the same outcome persists. fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")

Comment: If the length of the line isn't the issue is it possible that the errant data has new line characters in?

Comment: Please check the bottom of my question I edited and added an example of a row which creates an extra row rolling over the extra alternates data.

Comment: Is there a way I could do an sql query which looks for every row that only has data in the alternates column and then appends it to the data in the alternates column before its index? Also there are some rows that are completely blank. So ideally if I had a statement which could remove all rows with no data, then takes all rows with only data in alternates and appends it to the data in the previous row at alternates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there is a new line character between the digit and comma - that should give you the basis for a patter to clean up the data

Before passing the file to `fopen` to begin processing individual rows you could try cleaning up the data

```
$csv_file='c:/temp/flaky.csv';/* change to suit your environment */
file_put_contents( $csv_file, preg_replace( "@(\r\n),@", ',', file_get_contents( $csv_file ) ) );
```

/* now open with `fopen` and proceed */

Example data ( basically repeated the example csv you cited )

```
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58,,5930-01-109-7580,,
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58,,5930-01-109-7580,,
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58,,5930-01-109-7580,,
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58,,5930-01-109-7580,,
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58
,,5930-01-109-7580,,
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58,,5930-01-109-7580,,
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58
,,5930-01-109-7580,,
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58
,,5930-01-109-7580,,
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58,,5930-01-109-7580,,
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58,,5930-01-109-7580,,
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58,,5930-01-109-7580,,
```

ran it through the cleaner as above and it produced a csv file with this content:

```
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58,,5930-01-109-7580,,
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58,,5930-01-109-7580,,
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58,,5930-01-109-7580,,
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58,,5930-01-109-7580,,
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58,,5930-01-109-7580,,
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58,,5930-01-109-7580,,
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58,,5930-01-109-7580,,
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58,,5930-01-109-7580,,
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58,,5930-01-109-7580,,
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58,,5930-01-109-7580,,
8869K6X,2POLE TOGGLE SWITCH,MS90311-781,58,58,,5930-01-109-7580,,
```

Comment: I am sorry I am not understanding what your saying exactly. What exactly is the code you posted doing? You state to begin processing individual rows. Are you saying I am not processing individual rows?

Comment: OHHHH Wait you're saying there is a comma separating the data in that column?

Comment: No - there is a linebreak character in the data that is breaking your csv import. I don't know if it always appears at the same point or always after a number but that shouldn't matter. The code I posted should open the csv file and run a `preg_replace` on the `\r\n` characters and replace them - with a single comma so as to keep the data columns the same and then saves it back to the same file again. Once it is saved you can process the csv as you were initially with `fopen` and `fgetcsv`

Comment: Man your right I copied and pasted it in and bam fixed everything! Thanks a ton. Quick question. I suspect that the next file they are going to give me will have chars that need to be escaped in the Product column and possible the alternates column. Is there a way to write this so that no matter what it will always place the data without causing the insert query to break?

Comment: Obviously a comma in the data of the product column could cause problems potentially - there is no way to answer without seeing the data but you could employ a similar approach as here perhaps - cleanse the data first before trying to parse it with fgetcsv. For a csv with 88k rows it might not be the fastest method of cleansing but.... anyway, good luck - glad it helped.

Comment: Ok great. Thanks a ton this was going to be what I got stuck doing all day tomorrow. I am not very experienced with these specific things. So basically your code just says if there is a new line character in any of my data between the , on a row ignore it? Where is a place I could read up on this to make sense of what you gave me?

Comment: it doesn't ignore it - it replaces `\r\n,` with `,` ~ to read up on it try the php manual ( either on your system or the php.net website )